# how to cancel print job in cannon lbp3108b in ubuntu 16.04lts

Tags: printing

how to cancel print job in cannon  lbp3108b in ubuntu 16.04lts

I have given print command by mistake of 110 pages and I want to cancel print command but I am unable to cancel the print command. I tried to cancel the print command from printer menu. but there is no option of delete print.

Answer (score 1):

maybe doing :

```
lpstat -o
```

to find the printer and then:

```
cancel -a {printer}
```

or `cancel -a -x` to cancel all actual job list

To see all printer available do : `lpstat -p`